# Jenkins multibranch pipeline build mysteriously setting origin to local repo

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins to perform a multi-branch pipeline build using a github repo, this my checkout stage, contains a single line: checkout scm

However, when I instigate builds on any of the branches other than master, I get the following:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (git checkout)
[Pipeline] git
 > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url file:///C:/Projects/Demo 
# timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from file:///C:/Projects/Demo
```

Its almost as if my repo on GitHub things that its origin is on my laptop, can someone advise as to what is awry here ?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured this out, the answer is in two parts, firstly the "Critical section" that is wrapped by the lock command needs to be present in the Jenkinsfile associated with each branch:

```
stage('start container') {
        steps {
            RemoveContainer()
            timeout(time: 20, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                lock ('create SQL Server container') {
                    StartContainer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and secondly, the commands to get the next available port and spin-up the container need to be in the same method that is wrapped by lock.